# Need to output the results of a PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

I am currently using a script to pull information from monitors such as Manufacturer, Model, and Serial Number. At the moment the script exports the file to a folder that has already been created. I am needing to modify the script so it can automatically create the folder and file.

Script:

```
$Monitors = Get-WmiObject WmiMonitorID -Namespace root\wmi
$LogFile = "C:\test\monitors.txt"

function Decode {
    if ($args[0] -is [System.Array]){
        [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($args[0])
    }
    Else {
        "Not Found"
    }
}

echo "Manufacturer", "Name", "Serial Number"

ForEach ($Monitor in $Monitors) {
    $Manufacturer = Decode $Monitor.ManufacturerName -nomatch 0
    $Name = Decode $Monitor.UserFriendlyName -nomatch 0
    $Serial = Decode $Monitor.SerialNumberID -nomatch 0

    echo "$Manufacturer, $Name, $Serial" >> $LogFile
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? What have you tried?

Comment: The problem is that the script currently needs me to manually create the folder. I have tried using Out-File -FilePath "C:\test\monitors.txt" but it runs into an error saying that the path doesn't exist. I am needing help figuring out where to put the: Out-File -FilePath "C:\test\monitors.txt" command instead of using $LogFile = "C:\test\monitors.txt"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not export to CSV?(:

```
$Monitors = Get-WmiObject WmiMonitorID -Namespace root\wmi
$LogFile = "C:\test\monitors.csv"

function Decode {
    if ($args[0] -is [System.Array]){
        [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString($args[0])
    }
    Else {
        "Not Found"
    }
}

$Manufacturer= @()
$Name = @()
$Serial = @()

ForEach ($Monitor in $Monitors) {
    $Manufacturer += Decode $Monitor.ManufacturerName -nomatch 0
    $Name += Decode $Monitor.UserFriendlyName -nomatch 0 
    $Serial += Decode $Monitor.SerialNumberID -nomatch 0 
}

$obj = for($i=0; $i -lt $Monitors.Count;$i++){
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Manufacturer = $($Manufacturer[$i])
        Name = $($Name[$i])
        Serial = $($Serial[$i])
    } 
} 
$obj
$obj | Export-Csv -Path $LogFile -NoTypeInformation
```